# TimeOut Exception while doRpcCall-Importing contacts in TeleGram java API

Tags: java, api, telegram

I am trying to add and import a contact for sending message but i am getting time out exception every time.
Correct me if something is wrong.

Code:

```
TLInputContact tlic=new TLInputContact(1, PhNo, Fname, Lname);
TLVector contacts = new TLVector<>();
contacts.add(tlic);
TLRequestContactsImportContacts importContacts = new TLRequestContactsImportContacts(contacts, true);
TLImportedContacts importedContacts = api.doRpcCall(importContacts);
TLAbsUser recipient=importedContacts.getUsers().get(0);
TLInputPeerContact peer = new TLInputPeerContact(recipient.getId());
TLRequestMessagesSendMessage sendMessageRequest = new TLRequestMessagesSendMessage(peer, "Test", rnd.nextInt());

TLAbsSentMessage sentMessage = api.doRpcCall(sendMessageRequest);

Log::
    TelegramApi#1001:Timeout Iteration
    ActorDispatcher:Dispatching action: schedule for scheduller
    ActorDispatcher:Dispatching action: schedule for scheduller
    TelegramApi#1001:Timeout Iteration
    TelegramApi#1001:RPC #3: Timeout (15001 ms)
    Exception in thread "main" org.telegram.api.engine.TimeoutException
        at org.telegram.api.engine.TelegramApi.doRpcCall(TelegramApi.java:364)
        at org.telegram.api.engine.TelegramApi.doRpcCall(TelegramApi.java:309)
        at org.telegram.api.engine.TelegramApi.doRpcCall(TelegramApi.java:400)
        at org.telegram.api.engine.TelegramApi.doRpcCall(TelegramApi.java:396)
        at testmsg.Testmsg.main(Testmsg.java:151)
        TelegramApi#1001:Timeout Iteration
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `doRpcCallSide` instead of `doRpcCall` in TelegramApi object.
It helped me.

Comment: thanks man, it saved my life. however, do you know what's the reason?

Comment: The only solution that worked for me too - Thanks a lot! Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 0):

It started working for me after I updated Server IP Address in the MemoryStateAPI class, as shown below -

```
public void start(boolean isTest) {
    connections = new HashMap<>();
    connections.put(1, new ConnectionInfo[]{
            new ConnectionInfo(1, 0, isTest ? "149.154.175.10" : "149.154.175.50", 443)
    });
}
```